# could be probably xcode malfunctioning

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to add an observer to a `NSNotificatonCenter` notification that I posted in code earlier but Xcode gives that exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[TurkI_s_Manga.DisplayMangaViewController setStuff:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to class 0x102ffd650'.

I am using the same structure three times in my code and only one of them causes that exception. So I tried to check the selector before try to use it like this:

```
println(self.respondsToSelector("setStuff:"))
if self.respondsToSelector("setStuff:"){
    println("it responses to selector set stuff")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(DisplayMangaViewController.self, selector: "setStuff:", name: "pagesNotification", object: UrlAndNameList.self)
}
```

This code block prints `true` and then `it responses to the selector set stuff` but when observer receives the notification it gives the exception mentioned above.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. It has *nothing* to do with this question. Also, any time you find yourself thinking that you have found a compiler error or something like that, think again because the chances of that are vanishingly small.

Comment: yeah I know but since I encounter kind of compiler error before I thought that it could be again. Also it does has something to do with this question I think.

Comment: It seems that you are adding the type (class) as an observer (which could work if `setStuff` is a type method). Perhaps you want `addObserver(self, ...)` ?

Comment: yes this is it. thank you! @MartinR

Comment: you are getting exception on this point UrlAndNameList.self check where u define this function setStuff it should have object of type UrlAndNameList.self in its parameter

Comment: If you run into bugs and think it's Xcode's fault, you have already lost.

Answer (score 2):

From my above comment: You are adding the *type* (class) as an observer (which could work if `setStuff` is a type method). What you probably want is

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, ...)
```

to add the *instance* `self` as an observer.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether one thing (self) responds to a selector, and then you add another thing (DisplayMangaViewController.self) as an observer, which doesn't respond to the selector. So please explain why you would think that's Xcode's fault and not your own mistake.

First rule of debugging: When things go wrong, it is *your* fault. *You* did something wrong. Find what *you* did wrong. There are millions of developers using Xcode. Do you really think if it got something trivial like this wrong, you wouldn't hear about it everywhere?

Comment: look body as I written I encountered a problem that was caused by xcode and resetting and rebuilding it worked so that I tought that maybe it could be something similar so that I written title "could be?" and sometimes people cannot be able to see the glasses on his eyes if you what I mean.